# What is the best approach to change mysql into postgresql in a ruby Project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Sorry, I am a new ruby programmer. I have a project that is using MySql database structure, and I want to change the MysqlDB to PostgreSQL. Is it possible to do this, if so how..?

What I this is, if I have to change the database.yml and change this specific file, when I run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` this will work without problems..

I have changed to PostgreSQL, already. When I run `rake db:create` I don't get any errors, but when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error :

```
rake db:migrate
== 20151021060955 CreatePackages: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:packages)
   -> 0.0079s
-- execute("ALTER TABLE packages AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

"PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE packages AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000"
```

The problem being, `AUTO_INCREMENT` is in mysql, I want to do `AUTO_INCREMENT` in postgresql as well. Here is the migrate package class I'm using:

```
class CreatePackages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :packages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :total
      t.attachment :avatar

      t.timestamps
    end
    execute("ALTER TABLE packages AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000")
  end
end
```

How can I do the same thing using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes it will work. But also replace the `gem 'mysql'` with `gem 'pg'` in your Gemfile. Then `bundle` it.

Comment: How good is your test suite? ActiveRecord doesn't really protect you from databases differences so the first problem you'll probably hit is any MySQL-specific behavior you've accidentally used.

Comment: What do you mean with "How good is your test suit?" be more specific, Yes it is my main concern, but I really need to change to postgresql

Comment: Pleas @NitinSrivastava and the other user than I can not tag! See my update, I have problems with db:migrate. Take a look a my description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seem the problem with your migration with `AUTO_INCREMENT` that use only by `mysql` not using with `pg` alternative of `AUTO_INCREMENT` is `SERIAL` in `pg` so could your replace `execute("ALTER TABLE packages AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000")` to `execute("SELECT setval('packages _id_seq', 100000)")` in your migration file should that work.